# C# Abstract class has another abstract class object

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract

I have few classes representing some measured data, at first `ICut` abstract class with derived `RoundCut` and `SquareCut` like this:

```
public abstract class ICut
{
}

public class RoundCut : ICut
{
    DoSomeWithRoundCut(){}
}

public class SquareCut : ICut
{
    DoSomeWithSquareCut(){}
}
```

Of course it contains some implementation but it isn't important for this question. `ICut` is abstract class instead of interface because it has some implemetation itself.

Then, here are classes representing set of `ICut` data, again base abstract `IRoll` and derived `RoundRoll` and `SquareRoll`:

```
public abstract class IRoll
{
    // list of measured cuts
    public List<ICut> cuts;     

    // Create new cut
    public abstract ICut CreateCut();
}

public class RoundRoll : IRoll
{        
    public RoundRoll ()
    {
        cuts = new List<RoundCut>();
    }

    public override ICut CreateCut()
    {
        RoundCut cut = new RoundCut();
        cuts.Add(cut);
        return cut;
    }
}

public class SquareRoll : IRoll
{
    public SquareRoll()
    {
        cuts = new List<SquareCut>();
    }

    public override ICut CreateCut()
    {
        SquareCut cut = new SquareCut();
        cuts.Add(cut);
        return cut;
    }
}
```

And now, of course I'm not able to reach directly `RoundCut` or `SquareCut` extra implementation by calling for example:

```
IRoll roll = new RoundRoll();
roll.CreateCut();
roll.cuts[0].DoSomeWithRoundRoll();
```

And I can't use neither:

```
(roll.cuts[0] as RoundCut).DoSomeWithRoundRoll();
```

because I generally don't know if which `IRoll` derivation `roll` is.

I'm refactoring huge project where all `roll` objects were of type `RoundRoll` and now the other has to be added.

Maybe I'm missing some kind of suitable design pattern, I'm in the begining of advanced OOP patterns learning curve, and I've been thinking about solution of this problem all the day.

**UPDATE**
After many experiments, I realized that as a contrary to my primary opinions, I ended up with the solution of @The-First-Tiger with some improvements. I created simple factory:

```
// Cut factory
public static class CutFactory
{
    // Get new cut by given shape type
    public static ICut GetCut(RollShape shape)
    {
        switch (shape)
        {
            case RollShape.Round:
                return new RoundCut();
            case RollShape.Square:
                return new SquareCut();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

So I can create Cut like:

```
ICut cut = CutFactory.GetCut(roll.GetShape());
```

And if needed to have different behavior:

```
if (cut is RoundCut) 
    (cut as RoundCut).RoundCutSpecificMethod();
else if (cut is SquareCut) 
    (cut as SquareCut).SquareCutSpecificMethod();
```

Comment: Why not simply put a abstract DoSomething method in your abstract class so you can call it no matter what concrete type it is? Also ISomething is a convention for interfaces not abstract classes, I think.

Comment: Did you considered using generics? For example you could make the `IRoll` interface generic like `IRoll<TCut> where TCut: ICut`.

Comment: `cuts = new List<RoundCut>();` and `cuts = new List<SquareCut>();` is not supposed to compile, either.

Comment: Several issues there, do yourself a favor - lookup "uncle bob solid" on YouTube.

Comment: Your naming is a bit odd for C# standards. Interfaces are the only things that are prefixed with `I`, abstract classes don't normally get prefixes.

Comment: You are right, I'll use `I` prefix only for Interfaces in future.

Comment: You should just add `DoSomething` method to your abstract ICut class. Then override it in both classes `RoundCat` and `SquareCut`. That way you will always call `DoSomething` method and you don't care of type of a caller. Something similar to what you already did with `CreateCut` method. I think that is more strait forward and cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Amit: Thank you for youtube recommendation. Can you please write here some concrete issues of my code? Thanks.

Comment: Most notably I'd separate the object creation from the list management. Now you can have a `CutFactory` and a `Roll` which is a container+logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your code using interfaces:

```
public interface ICut
{
   DoSomething();
}

public class RoundCut : ICut
{
    DoSomething(){}
}

public class SquareCut : ICut
{
    DoSomething(){}
}
```

---

```
public interface IRoll
{
    IEnumerable<ICut> Cuts { get; };      

    ICut CreateCut();
}

public class RoundRoll : IRoll
{        
    public IEnumerable<ICut> Cuts { get; private set; }

    public RoundRoll ()
    {
        this.Cuts = new List<ICut>();
    }

    public ICut CreateCut()
    {
        var cut = new RoundCut();
        this.Cuts.Add(cut);

        return cut;
    }
}

public class SquareRoll : IRoll
{
    public IEnumerable<ICut> Cuts { get; private set; }

    public SquareRoll ()
    {
        this.Cuts = new List<ICut>();
    }

    public ICut CreateCut()
    {
        var cut = new SquareCut();
        this.Cuts.Add(cut);

        return cut;
    }
}
```

---

```
IRoll roll = new RoundRoll();
var cut = roll.CreateCut();
cut.DoSomething();
```

---

### Update

If SquareCut and RoundCut have a lot of methods which are not common you can still check for ICuts concrete type and then cast to it:

```
IRoll roll = new RoundRoll();
var cut = roll.CreateCut();

if (cut is RoundCut) {
    (cut as RoundCut).RoundCutSpecificMethod();
}
else if (cut is SquareCut) {
    (cut as SquareCut).SquareCutSpecificMethod();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need keep also some data members inside `IRoll`, so I need to use abstract class for this.

Comment: You could still put a DoSomething method in the abstract class instead of the derivative? Otherwise you could test with if (roll.cuts[0] is RoundCut) -> cast to RoundCut

Comment: Ok I follow you. Problem is that DoSomething can't be common for RoundCut and SquareCut. Each derivate contains many methods. What has at least something common, I've tried to move to ICut as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for update. I need to check the type and cast IRoll object depending on my logic. Following your code, I would need also check ICut type and cast to concrete type afterwards every time when I would need acces cut. It would work but with huge effort in this case. The solution using generic will satisfy this problem more easily I guess.

Answer (score 4):

One way to work around the problem is to make `IRoll` generic on the type of its `ICut`:

```
public abstract class AbstractRoll<T> where T : ICut, new {
    // list of measured cuts
    public List<T> cuts = new List<T>();
    // Create new cut
    public T CreateCut() {
       var res = new T();
       curs.Add(res);
       return res;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public class RoundRoll : AbstractRoll<RoundCut> {
    ...
}

public class SquareRoll : AbstractRoll<SquareCut> {
    ...
}
```

Note that C# lets you move the boilerplate code to the base class by applying constraints to generic types.

The only remaining issue now is that `AbstractRoll` is no longer a common interface for `RoundRoll` and `SquareRoll`, so you cannot create a collection of rolls.

This problem can be solved by adding a non-generic interface `IRoll` on top of `AbstractRoll` class, with the operations that are common to all rolls, and are also independent of the type of the roll's `ICut`:

```
public interface IRoll {
    IEnumerable<ICut> Cuts { get; }
    ... // add other useful methods here
}
public abstract class AbstractRoll<T> : IRoll where T : ICut, new {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ICut> Cuts {
        get {
            return curs.Cast<ICut>();
        }
    }
    ... // implement other useful methods here
}
```

Comment: This make sense, generic could solve my problem. Thanks! I'll try to follow this model.

Comment: Now, I can't of course use `IRoll roll;` instance, also I can't use `IRoll<ICut> roll;` as it isn't implementation of `ICut`. But how to use it when I need to work with generic `IRoll` object? Thanks

Comment: @Majak That's what I tried to address in the second part of the answer. I renamed `IRoll` to `AbstractRoll`, and added a little sample code to illustrate what I meant.